# Address of a range in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I use the following code to copy a selection's address to a variable (only visible cells), but only a maximum of 255 characters are copied to it. If address is longer than 255 characters it is limited. It is suppossed that string variables can be 63000 characters long, isn't it? How can I solve this? Thank you very much in advance.

The code:

```
Sel=Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address(False, False)
```

Variable content:

```
C6:C10,C12:C13,C15:C27,C29:C31,C33:C54,C56:C64,C66,C68:C71,C73:C81,C83:C84,C86:C87,C89:C101,C103:C122,C124:C132,C135:C155,C158:C162,C164:C166,C168:C187,C189:C192,C194:C199,C201:C212,C214,C216:C233,C235:C251,C253:C262,C264:C267,C269:C270,C272:C292,C294
```

(251 characters)

What it should looks like (for example):

```
C6:C10,C12:C13,C15:C27,C29:C31,C33:C54,C56:C64,C66,C68:C71,C73:C81,C83:C84,C86:C87,C89:C101,C103:C122,C124:C132,C135:C155,C158:C162,C164:C166,C168:C187,C189:C192,C194:C199,C201:C212,C214,C216:C233,C235:C251,C253:C262,C264:C267,C269:C270,C272:C292,C294:C296,C299:C316
```

(266 characters)

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub adres()
    Dim r As Range, s As String, rr As Range
    Set r = Selection.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    s = ""

    For Each rr In r
        s = s & "," & rr.Address(0, 0)
    Next rr

    s = Mid(s, 2)
    MsgBox s
End Sub
```

You can use `Areas` if you want to "condense" the string a little.